# How to display sonarqube stats in full screen

Tags: c#, sonarqube

We just upgraded from sonarqube 6.0 to 6.7.

Previously we were having some dashboard where we were having metrics(% code coverage, number of units tests, ...).

I cannot find this anymore, was this part of some plugin? Has this been moved?

Answer (score 2):

Dashboards were removed in SonarQube 6.2, but you should be able to find what you're looking for in your project's Measure space. It contains all the metric domains, shows all (visible) metrics, and includes several different views of each metric:

[image]

Comment: Well.. It was displayed on the big screen of our dev room to follow the errors of units tests and their code coverage. I tried to play with your Measure tab, but I was unable to have code coverage, units tests error count and unit tests count. This is kind of a no-go for us, I think we will revert to the V6 until this feature is reintroduced. Do you have an idea when it will? Why has it been removed?

Comment: It will not be reintroduced. If you need to feed a wallboard, you should look at the Web API link in your SQ footer to pull the required data.

Comment: Seriously? Why has this been removed?